# zf2 File Upload required and file is already uploaded - how to display file and pass validation?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a file upload element in my form. I am using the PRG method to move and rename the file:

```
$params = array(
    'target' => $moduleConfig['files']['dir'].'/myFile',
    'randomize' => true,
    'use_upload_extension' => true
);
$filters[] = new File\RenameUpload($params); // Will be added to the filters on the element
```

This successfully moves and stores the file in the desired location.

I store the file array in the database for reference.

The file upload element is a required field, but I have now uploaded my image so the next time I navigate to the edit form I would like a couple of things to happen:

1. The image that has been uploaded to be displayed (I have already got this working)
2. The form to validate even though I don't select a file to upload (because I've already uploaded a file)

At the moment I can't get (2) to work.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is probably to check if the file was previously uploaded, and if so, use [setValidationGroup()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups) to exclude the file upload validator.